# Finding the area available for the date range

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

Suppose you have a room which is 100sqft and you want to rent it from 1st Aug to 31st Aug.
Bookings Table schema

```
startdate|enddate|area|storageid
```

you have following bookings

```
06-Aug|25-Aug|50|'abc'
05-Aug|11-Aug|40|'xyz'
18-Aug|23-Aug|30|'pqr'
13-Aug|16-Aug|10|'qwe'
```

Now somebody requests for booking from 08-Aug to 20-Aug. For this date range the maximum area available is 10sqft (Since, for dates 8,9,10 and 11 Aug only 10sq ft is available.)

How would you create an efficient SQL query to get this? Right now I have very messy and inefficient query which gives wrong results for some cases. I am not posting the query because It is so messy that I can't explain it myself.

I don't necessarily want to solve it using SQL only. If there is an algorithm that can solve it efficiently I would extract all the data from database.

Comment: Who dreamt up that way of saving date data?

Comment: Mysql and sql server are 2 different products. Pls remove the irrelevant product tag. Pls also include what you have tried and what issues you are experiencing. At the moment your question is more lik:e give me the code. There are quite a few questions on SO around reservations. Have you checked them out?

Comment: @Drew: Ignore the format for dates. I am saving dates in YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: @Shadow: I have tried creating a sql query which is very messy and confusing hence, I did not include it. I did not look for SO specifically for reservations related questions, although I googled a lot for this and could not find any acceptable solutions

Comment: show the output from `show create table myTable` (if mysql). Show that output for all relevant tables (there clearly are more than one).

Comment: @Shadow: Also, I believe my question is different from other reservations problems because I can have 2 reservations in the same room. for example I can have 2 reservations for 50sqft in the same room for the same date.

Comment: Better yet [What is sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899464) . But you should already know that because you have almost 100 points in this tag. And you know how to spot a question that is answerable compared to one that is not supported by the op.

Comment: I didn't get this line *For this date range the maximum area available is 10sqft*. Could you please explain how?

Comment: 1) I just can't bother to answer a complicated question where the OP does not demonstrate any own effort and just asks for code. 2) The logic behind reserving rooms and reserving area is the same. You have a resource constraint, you have a demand, and you have to check if your available resource (room or area) is sufficient throughout a given period.

Comment: @1000111: If you calculate for each day (total space available) - (space already booked), you can see that for date range 08-aug to 20-aug you can only give 10sqft because for dates 08-aug to 11-aug only 10sqft is available

Comment: @Shadow: Answer to 2) I have a resource constraint, but I dont have demand. The user does not specify how many sqft he/she wants, which makes it more complicated. The user only specifies the date range.

Answer (score 0):

Someone removed SQL Server, but here is the algorithm:

```
DECLARE @startDate date = '2016-08-09';
DECLARE @endDate date = '2016-08-20';
DECLARE @totalArea decimal(19,2) = 100;

WITH Src AS --Your source table
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('2016-08-06', '2016-08-25', 50, 'abc'),
    ('2016-08-05', '2016-08-11', 40, 'xyz'),
    ('2016-08-18','2016-08-23',30,'pqr'),
    ('2016-08-13','2016-08-16',10,'qwe')
    )T(startdate, enddate, area, storageid)
), Nums AS --Numbers table 0..N, N must be greater than ranges calculated
(
    SELECT 0 N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 N FROM Nums
    WHERE N<DATEDIFF(DAY,@startDate,@endDate)
) --Query
--You can use total-maxUsed from range of days
SELECT @totalArea-MAX(Used) FROM
(
    --Group by day, sum all used areas
    SELECT MidDate, SUM(Used) Used FROM
    (
        --Join table with numbers, split every day, if room used, return area
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, N, @startDate) MidDate, CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, N, @startDate) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate THEN area END Used
        FROM Src
        CROSS APPLY Nums
    ) T
    GROUP BY MidDate
) T
```

Comment: That someone was the OP. This probably means that the OP uses MySQL.

Comment: I leave this since no other answers appeared, as an algorithmic solution. The most important part below `--Query` is almost universal (except parameters and `DATEADD`)